# How do I make Vim do normal (Bash-like) tab completion for file names?

Tags: vim

When I'm opening a new file in Vim and I use tab completion, it completes the whole file name instead of doing the partial match like Bash does. Is there an option to make this file name tab completion work more like Bash?

Comment: Technically speaking, I'm pretty sure "bash" doesn't do any tab completion. It's readline that does that.

Comment: We are talking about customize the behavior of the ^X^F feature?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

I personally use

```
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmenu
```

When you type the first tab hit, it will complete as much as possible. The second tab hit will provide a list. The third and subsequent tabs will cycle through completion options so you can complete the file without further keys.

Bash-like would be just

```
set wildmode=longest,list
```

but the full is very handy.

Comment: I wish this were the default behavior in vim. I though there was no getting around to full tab completion until I saw this post.

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar I recommend maintaining a dotfiles archive to make it easy to deploy in new environments

Comment: I set this in my `~/.bashrc` file. So the line I've got in there looks like this: `alias vim='vim -c "set number" "+syntax on" "+set wildmode=longest,list,full" "+set wildmenu"'`

Comment: Is there a way to start full only when there are few results? something like `set wildmode=longest,5full,list`. With lot results full is useless but very handy with few. It will be perfect with something like "show full only if completion fits on one line screen"

Comment: Is it possible to have a similar behavior for :tag command? It seems it does not complete as much as possible after the first tab hit.

Comment: This used to be working in the past (gVim/ubuntu) but now it does not (macvim8.x/macOS). See [example](http://prnt.sc/dmazoc). Any ideas?

Comment: After tolerating the origin tab completion for 2 month, I think there must be a way to simplify it. Thank you.

Answer (score 39):

The closest behavior to Bash's completion should be

```
set wildmode=longest:full,full
```

With a few character typed, pressing tab once will give all the matches available in **`wildmenu`**. This is different to the answer by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526940/1057593) which opens a quickfix-like window beneath the command-line.

Then you can keep typing the rest of the characters or press tab again to auto-complete with first match and circle around it.

Comment: I think I prefer this way.

Comment: Same! With this way, you can still press <C-d> if you want to see the full list.

Comment: Thanks! This was the desired behavior. I clearly didn't understand the documentation, but after a second read, it is quite obvious: _"Completion mode that is used for the character specified with 'wildchar'... Each part specifies what to do for each consecutive use of 'wildchar'.  The first part specifies the behavior for the first use of 'wildchar', The second part for the second use, etc."_ :help wildmode

Comment: This is really useful, but to nitpick: @michael is correct `wildmode=longest,list` is the closest to default bash/readline behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

Apart from the suggested wildmode/wildmenu, Vim also offers the option to show all possible completions by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This might be helpful for some users that stumble across this question when searching for different autocompletion options in Vim like I did.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to set the wildmenu, you can always press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> when you want to open a file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will complete the filename like Bash completion.

Comment: Ctrl-L does not act like bash autocomplete. It does not cycle through all possible options.

Comment: My bash _does_ act like that. `<Tab>` completes the current string as far as is unambiguously possible (like `CTRL-L` in Vim) and `<Tab><Tab>` shows a list of possible matches (like `CTRL-D` in Vim).

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you are using autocomplete in Vim via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to search through the current buffer. When you use this command, you get a list of solutions; simply repeat the command to go to the next item in the list. The same is true for all autocomplete commands. While they fill in the entire word, you can continue to move through the list until you arrive at the one you wish to use.

This may be a more useful command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. The only difference is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> searches backwards in the buffer while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> searches forwards... Realistically, they will both provide a list with the same elements, and they may just appear in a different order.

Answer (score 2):

Run these:

```
:set nocompatible
:set wildmenu
:set wildmode=longest:full
```

`longest:full` gives you a Bash-like completion with:

- suggestions in a single line
- Tab completing only what is certain
- Right/Ctrl-n | Left/Ctrl-p to select suggestions.

[image: Preview of described feature]

From the help:

```
If you prefer the <Left> and <Right> keys to move the cursor instead
of selecting a different match, use this:
      :cnoremap <Left> <Space><BS><Left>
      :cnoremap <Right> <Space><BS><Right>
```

Comment: Yeah, I pressed Tab after w i l. It added the d and showed the options. Did you run ```set wildmode=longest:full``` before and it still didn't work?

Comment: @Flimm It should now work! Added `nocompatible` and `wildmenu` to the answer. I think I got the wildmenu information from this video, it shows lots of tips using native Vim features: https://youtu.be/XA2WjJbmmoM.

Comment: Tip: run `vim --clean` on the command-line to run Vim with a clean configuration, so you can test options out without any plugins interfering

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:set wildmenu`. Apart from that, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying.

Oh, yeah, and maybe try this link: [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_bash_completion_with_ctags_and_Vim)