# Resources concerning Python scripting in Vim

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to learn a little about python scripting in GVim, but I'm having trouble with starting. Elementary things, really.

Are there any resources / tutorials concerting python scripting in Vim out there ? Simple examples which show the basic principles, would be welcomed also.

Answer (score 23):

Here is all I know of in terms of such docs:

- [A nice presentation by Sean Reifschneider](http://www.tummy.com/Community/Presentations/vimpython-20070225/vim.html)
- [The "official" VIM Python Interface reference](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html)
- [some shorter notes](http://zerokspot.com/weblog/2009/02/22/getting-to-know-vims-python-interface/)
- [Extending Vim With Python](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/extending-vim-with-python/6310729)

Comment: The "official" link is obsolete; check http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html instead.

Comment: @Bach Thanks. I've edited the answer as you suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

:help python-vim is a good start. The best vim resource is always at your fingertips and the sooner you get used to referring to it the better you will get at vim overall.

I got better at searching vim help with this..

[How do I make vim do normal (bash like) tab completion for file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names/526940#526940)

also :he vim-script-intro

I'd also recommend looking straight at the source of existing plugins that do something similar to what you want to do. That way you cut out the middle man and dont have to deal with blog ads and other distractions.

Answer (score 4):

#### Vimscript The Hard Way

Have you checked out [Learn Vimscript The Hard Way](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2914)?  It is an excellent read.

#### Scripting Vim With Python

vim 7.0 and above can be compiled with the `+python` flag, which gives vim Python support.  This is a (albeit, somewhat extreme) path to getting the language support you want.

**Links**

- [I Code With Things And Stuff](http://blog.raynes.me/blog/2012/02/01/i-code-with-things-and-stuff/) delves a into how to extend your editor with a scripting language like Python.
- [Extending Vim With Python](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/extending-vim-with-python/6310729) seems like more of a reference for the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the *Scripting* chapter in ['A Byte of Vim'](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/vim/).