# How to warn before opening certain filetypes in vim?

Tags: bash, vim

It is easy to accidentally open a large binary or data file with vim when relying on command line autocomplete.

Is it possible to add an interactive warning when opening certain file types in vim?

For example, I'd like to add a warning when opening files without an extension:

```sh
> vim someBinary
Edit someBinary? [y/N]
```

Or maybe:

```sh
> vim someBinary
# vim buffer opens and displays warning about filetype, 
# giving user a chance to quit before loading the file
```

This could be applied to a range of extensions, such as `.pdf`, `.so`, `.o`, `.a`, no extension, etc.

There is a related question on [preventing vim from opening binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793207/prevent-vim-from-opening-binary-files-accidentally), but it is primarily about modifying autocomplete to prevent accidentally opening the files in the first place.

Comment: This post may solve your problem: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/how-can-i-cancel-reading-a-file-into-a-buffer-on-bufreadpre

Comment: Thanks - that seems like a good mechanism to implement this. I'll post my final solution when I'm done tweaking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution I came up with, using vim autocommands with the `BufReadCmd` event. It's a lot of vimscript, but it's pretty robust. It issues a warning if the file being opened is a non-ascii file or has a blacklisted extension (`.csv` and `.tsv` for this example):

```
augroup bigfiles
   " Clear the bigfiles group in case defined elsewhere
   autocmd!
   " Set autocommand to run before reading buffer
   autocmd BufReadCmd * silent call PromptFileEdit()
augroup end



" Prompt user input if editing an existing file before reading
function! PromptFileEdit()
    " Current file
    let file = expand("%")
    " Whether or not we should continue to open the file
    let continue = 1

    " Skip if file has an extension or is not readable
    if filereadable(file) && (IsNonAsciiFile(file) || IsBlacklistedFile())
        " Get response from user
        let response = input('Are you sure you want to open "' . file . '"? [y/n]')

        " Bail if response is a 'n' or contains a 'q'
        if response ==? "n" || response =~ "q"
            let continue = 0
            if (winnr("$") == 1)
                " Quit if it was the only buffer open
                quit
            else
                " Close buffer if other buffers open
                bdelete
            endif
        endif
    endif

    if continue == 1
        " Edit the file
        execute "e" file
        " Run the remaining autocommands for the file
        execute "doautocmd BufReadPost" file
    endif

endfunction

" Return 1 if file is a non-ascii file, otherwise 0
function! IsNonAsciiFile(file)
    let ret = 1
    let fileResult = system('file ' . a:file)
    " Check if file contains ascii or is empty
    if fileResult =~ "ASCII" || fileResult =~ "empty" || fileResult =~ "UTF"
        let ret = 0
    endif
    return ret
endfunction

" Return 1 if file is blacklisted, otherwise 0
function! IsBlacklistedFile()
    let ret = 0
    let extension = expand('%:e')

    " List contains ASCII files that we don't want to open by accident
    let blacklistExtensions = ['csv', 'tsv']

    " Check if we even have an extension
    if strlen(extension) == 0
        let ret = 0
    " Check if our extension is in the blacklisted extensions
    elseif index(blacklistExtensions, extension) >= 0
        let ret = 1
    endif

    return ret
endfunction
```

To read with syntax highlighting enabled, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ben-albrecht/41899592d49b6576f4389cdfcd5df4c2).

Maybe not super elegant, but I enjoyed learning some vimscript along the way.

I am not too experienced with vimscript so I'm sure there is room for improvements -- suggestions and alternative solutions welcome.

Note: This is not expected to work on Windows systems outside of WSL or Cygwin, due to calling `file`.

Comment: Colons not necessary on bd or q (though i would prefer to see most commands spelled out, since its a func and not interactive). You also probably want call PromptFileEdit...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- I'll update when I get a chance. Not following what you mean by "You also probably want call PromptFileEdit..."

Comment: `exe PromptFileEdit() -> call PromptFileEdit()` (since it doesn't return anything to execute)

Comment: That system call to file wont be portable, but you may not care. Its almost certain to be *slow*

Comment: You will soon learn that there are two types of vimscripters. The one who writes stuff just for his/her vim instance and the one who writes vimscript for plugins. For plugins it has to be portable and compatible with as much vim (and nvim) versions as possible. So please to not get demotivated from feedback here. Some persons here are writing vim plugins since decades =)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I assume you mean that `file` will not be portable beyond POSIX-compliant systems, i.e. it won't work on Windows -- is that correct?

Comment: @bencray pretty much—any system lacking the file utility.

Comment: I'm not personally worried about supporting Windows my solution, but that's a good point. I'll mention it in my answer. As for performance, I'm sure there's many improvements to be made, but the impact of the change on timing with `vim --startuptime` was negligible.

Comment: Thanks for this well written script. Although I have no interest in guarding against opening big files (taking vim out behind the barn every once in a while is at least mildly cathartic), I am going to employ this method as a very maintainable way to guard against haphazardly opening up code files that happen to be in the autogenerated parts of the project tree... a far more insidious mistake that could be made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this

```
promptvim() { 
   grep -Fq "." <<< "$1" || read -p "Edit $1? [y/N]" && [[ $REPLY == "y" ]] || return
   /usr/bin/vim "$1"
}
```

You can choose a different function name. When you use `vim` other scripts might fail.

EDIT:
When you like this construction  (wrapper, not vim settings), you can make the function better with more tests:

```
promptvim() {
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "arguments are missing"
      return
   fi
   local maybe_dot=$(grep -Fq "." <<< "$1")
   for file in $*; do
      # skip tests when creating a new file
      if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
         maybe_dot=$(grep -F "." <<< "${file}")
         if (( ${#maybe_dot} == 0 )); then
            read -p "Edit ${file}? [y/N]"
            # check default response variable REPLY
            # Convert to lowercase and check other ways of confirming too
            if [[ ! "${REPLY,,}" =~ ^(y|yes|j|ja|s|si|o|oui)$ ]]; then
               continue
            fi
         fi
      fi
      echo /usr/bin/vim "${file}"
   done
}
```

This still not covers all special cases. You might want to add support of the `vim` parameters on the commandline, check for an interactive session and think what you want with `here documents`.

Comment: Spell out the conditional with if, yeah? No need for a long chain of ands and ors (which may not behave exactly as you wish in some edge cases)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I added some edge cases. It becomes more and more complex, I am tempted to add some "unit tests" proving the cases for existing and new files, different argument lists and responses to the question. I did some tests, and leave this as an exercise for the OP.