# Can vi help me with typing my paths?

Tags: vi

I would like some help from vi to type long winding system paths, the same way my shells do it for me. I am certain there is a way to it...

linke if I am in a config file and need to type a path

Eggs =
    /Us|

(the pipe being the cursor), what would I have to do to expand this to /Users/myname/somedir/...

Comment: If you're talking about making vim's tab completion like bash's say, then there's a question about that here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names. Ah sorry - that's vim (it's probably different in vi - but I leave this here in case it helps.)

Comment: No, this is really just of getting *to* vi/m`s tab completion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There's a vim script called [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) that I think will do what you want.</strike>

<strike>Quoting the docs (emphasis mine):</strike>

> <strike>Currently super tab can recognize
>   method calls or attribute references
>   via '.', '::' or '->', **and file path
>   references containing '/'**</strike>.

---

It seems this can be done without a script, `Ctrl-X` `Ctrl-F` does it nicely.

Comment: Cool, thanks - I have a look into this (though I was under the impression that vim should be able to do this on it's own, maybe I mixed it up with emacs there)

Comment: @Jan. Sorry it took a while, but you're right; it can be done without a script. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Cool, I even get a drop down menu (I still have to find out how I keep it open after the first path segment, though)