# Vim command line mode - how to confirm selection?

Tags: vim

In zsh, if you type `ls <Tab>` in your home dir, it'll show all non-hidden files in your home, then each `<Tab>` cycle through the file names.

When the current highlighted filename is what I want, if that item is a dir, I type `/` to confirm my selection, if it's a file, I use `<Space>`.

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names) instructs, I have added these two lines in my `.vimrc`  to give vim zsh-like completion.

```
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmenu
```

But when vim is cycling through the options, how can I confirm a selection?
Like in my home dir I start vim, and `:e` + some tabs, when the selection is on my document dir, how can I confirm it? `<Enter>` would finish the command, `<Esc>` or `<C-c>` cancels it, while `/` appends a backslash so the command becomes `:e document//`--not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the vim documentation (:help wildmenu):

```
While the "wildmenu" is active the following keys have special meanings:

[...]
<Down> - in filename/menu name completion: move into a subdirectory or submenu
[...]
```

So I think that gets at least part of what you're after.

Comment: I always thought vim bashes against using Arrow keys, so I somehow overlooked this command in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else (like me) ends up here and feel like @Geoff answer doesn't feel really vim-like.

I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> does exactly what OP was asking. More information in `:help cmdline-completion`

Answer (score 0):

I use `<space>` to select.

```
cnoremap <expr> <space>  wildmenumode()?"\<space>\<BS>":"\<space>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I was looking for the same answer. According to `:help wildmenu`:

```
CTRL-Y      - accept the currently selected match and stop
              completion.
```