# Rails.vim tab complete doesn't halt at multiple possibilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

When I use [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails)'s tab complete with `:E` (or any other method) it autocompletes a lot more forcefully that I'd like. For example if I want to go to the `admin/products` controller and I type `:Econtroller ad` and press tab, it might complete to `:Econtroller addresses` or I guess the first possible match. I wish it stopped and let me type more.

Is this an issue in rails.vim? Vim itself? Or a failure of my configuration?

I'm using MacVim v7.4. And the latest release of rails.vim installed via Vundle.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Based on the answer, yes it's a duplicate. I do all my fuzzy finding through CtrlP so I guess this is the first time I had interacted with Vim's standard tab completion.

Comment: Yeah, understandable because of the Rails.vim angle.  It's nothing personal, it's just better to have duplicates removed from SO.

Comment: What about using `:Econtroller ap` or maybe `a/p` followed by a tab?

Comment: @smathy I'm with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard way vim does tab completion, this other SO post should help you: [How do I make vim do normal (bash like) tab completion for file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526858/152786)