# Bash-like autocomplete behavior in vim with YouCompleteMe

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I have recently started to use YCM and I am happy. I am just not too fond of the way the auto completion writes its suggestion.

The behavior that I am observing (let's name it behavior 1) is that when there are several possibilities, hitting the autocomplete key cycle between suggestions and write the full currently selected suggestion. So far so good but not very practical when the number of suggestions is large.

What I would like to have is if there are several suggestions for the completion, complete at least the common denominator and wait for a character before selecting the remaining possibility with the new character (behavior 2. akind to default bash behavior)

The must would be to have behavior 2 by default and switching to behavior 1 when the auto complete key is typed, but I would settle for behavior 2.

I tried to set the wildmode to `set wildmode=longest,list,full` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names) but it does not seems to influence YCM, or at least not in the way I would want to.

Can Y configure YCM to behave like this ? Or should I make my own Completer ?

Comment: If you are really talking about the insert mode completion provided by YCM, then `:help 'wildmode'` is irrelevant as it relates to command-line completion. The relevant option is `:help 'completeopt'` but there is always a chance that those bloated plugins override native functionalities with their own… so YMMV.

Comment: completeotp does not seem to have any effect. The selection machinery may be probably internal to YCM.